# How to create an array with date records in swift

Tags: ios, swift, validation, date

I have an array with dates (users entries on website).
Example:

```
['2017-03-10 08:13:11', '2017-03-10 19:01:27', '2017-03-11 07:35:55', '2017-03-11 16:15:11', '2017-03-12 08:01:41', '2017-03-12 17:19:08']
```

and I have to validate each date. Is it possible to assign this record *'2017-03-10 08:13:11'* as a specific structure? I Need to identify this with variables, which I can use, like year-month-day etc. Or maybe any ideas how I can create array like this?

Best for me is to do it in swift, but If swift not fits You, share you idea with another language :)

Comment: Can you explain more what exactly you want?

Comment: @SyedQamarAbbas my program gets on entry an array with date records. I   have to check these dates (time between them, etc). To do it, I have to get to them in some way, to extract values

Comment: You mean when you want to get an object from this array you want separate day, month, year, hour, mint, sec individually in int format?
Right?

Comment: @SyedQamarAbbas right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Class for your date definition and add an extension of String because you want to convert a string date into your date.

```
extension String {
    func getMyDate() -> DateComponents {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS"
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: self)
        let dateComp = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date!)
        return dateComp
    }
}

let arrayOfDates = ["2017-03-10 08:13:11", "2017-03-10 19:01:27", "2017-03-11 07:35:55", "2017-03-11 16:15:11", "2017-03-12 08:01:41", "2017-03-12 17:19:08"]
//Now Select a date String from array
let selectedDate = arrayOfDates[0]
//Now Convert this string into your Above Class 'MyDate'
let myDate = selectedDate.getMyDate()
//Now You can use 
//myDate.hour
//myDate.minute
//myDate.second
//And so year, month, day etc
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use the built in [Date](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/date) structure of Swift and use a [DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/dateformatter) to construct Dates from your strings.